# WPF MediaPlayer: How to play in sequence, sync?

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

I have this function:

```
public static void Play(string FileName, bool Async = false)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer mp = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

        mp.Open(FileName.ToUri());
        mp.Play();
    }
```

When i call

```
Play(@"file1.mp3");
Play(@"file2.mp3");
Play(@"file3.mp3");
Play(@"file4.mp3");
```

all them play at same time.

How can i make MediaPlayer wait the end of the file, to play the next? What the function should like?

EDIT:

```
public static void Play(Uri FileName, bool Async = false)
    {
        AutoResetEvent a = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.MediaEnded += (o1, p1) =>
        {
            a.Set();
        };

        mp.MediaOpened += (o, p) =>
        {
            int total = Convert.ToInt32(mp.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

            mp.Play();
            if (!Async)
            {
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(total);
                a.WaitOne();
            }
        };

        mp.Open(FileName);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to have `Wait` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will share my Solution with you:

I created a Window: WindowPlay.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Sistema.Util.WindowPlay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WindowPlay" 
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Top="0" Left="0"
    Width="16" Height="16" 
    ShowActivated="False"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
>
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="MediaElement1" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Close"
                      MediaEnded="MediaElement1_MediaEnded" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

WindowPlay.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Sistema.Util
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WindowPlay.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WindowPlay : Window
    {
        public WindowPlay()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            catch
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Plays the specified file name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="FileName">The filename to play</param>
        /// <param name="Async">If True play in background and return immediatelly the control to the calling code. If False, Play and wait until finish to return control to calling code.</param>
        public static void Play(Uri FileName, bool Async = false)
        {
            WindowPlay w = new WindowPlay();

            var mp = w.MediaElement1;

            if (mp == null)
            {
                // pode estar sendo fechada a janela
                return;
            }
            mp.Source = (FileName);

            if (Async)
                w.Show();
            else
                w.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void MediaElement1_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for the current file to finish playing before calling `Play` on the next.

This you do by listening for the [MediaEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaended.aspx) event.

You'll need to listen for the event:

```
mp.MediaEnded += MediaEndedEventHandler;
```

However, you'll need to make the `MediaPlayer` object a static too so you only ever have one of them. Make sure you only add this handler the once. Then in the handler issue a new event to start playing the next file.

What you are implementing is a playlist. So you'll add the files to the playlist and then you'll need to keep a track of your current position in the playlist.

Comment: I am unable to make this work, could you please edit the code in my question to make it work?

Comment: @Tony - oh no. Don't use sleep. You need to subscribe to the `MediaEnded` event and then play the next track in that. You also might get further by making the method non static.